# MySQL Trigger: compare record with previous record before insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

When I  insert data in db I have to compare the current record with the previous one. If neccassary, some values of the current record needs to be modified.

I've tried some pieces of SQL like below, but all give SQL errors. This one gives me an error says that I select more than 1 records.

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE 
    TRIGGER set_moment_display
     BEFORE INSERT ON data
     FOR EACH ROW

     BEGIN
       DECLARE moment DATETIME;

       SELECT press_moment_1 INTO moment FROM data LIMIT 1;

       IF moment > NEW.press_moment_1 THEN SET NEW.press_moment_1 = moment;
       END IF;
     END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

How do I achieve what I've described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alias "OLD."

```
You can refer to columns in the subject table 
(the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases OLD and NEW. 
OLD.col_name refers to a column of an existing row before 
it is updated or deleted. NEW.col_name refers to the column 
of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated
```

**UPDATE**

Jim Garrison properly pointed up to me the mistake, "BEFORE INSERT" doesn't have "OLD." values, this alias works only for UPDATE and DELETE.

Comment: Doesn't that work only on update triggers?  There is no old value on an insert.

Comment: Ooopss... sorry for the mistake! I have realised now the "BEFORE INSERT"

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that, since a SQL database has no implicit concept of row ordering (you supply the ordering criteria on every query), there is no "previous" row for the trigger to look at.  The "previously inserted row" has no meaning in the context of an insert trigger.

Suppose for a moment that it did and there were several processes inserting rows in the table. When the trigger fired for process #1's insert, which row is the "previous" row? The one previously inserted by process #1? Suppose the chronologically "most recent" row was actually inserted by process #3?

If you need to do this it cannot be done in a trigger unless you can use a know key value to identify the row you understand as "most recent".  Otherwise it must be handled in the application that is doing the inserts.